# Ignore multiple folders using tree

Tags: tree

The command `tree -I 'node_modules'` prevents the `node_modules folder` from appearing in the output. Likewise, `tree -I 'app/ui/bower_components'` prevents `app/ui/bower_components` from appearing in the output.

However, `tree -I 'node_modules' -I 'app/ui/bower_components'` doesn't prevent both from appearing in the output. Instead, it appears the last one is used.

**So, how do you ignore multiple folders using `tree`?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `|` to separate patterns, in your example you can do

```
tree -I "node_modules|bower_components"
```

You need the double quotation marks so that bash won't interpret the pipe character.

If you look at the man pages for tree, read the one for the -P argument instead of the -I (just above).